# Controller for a Sequelize many-to-many relationship

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a controller in Sequelize for a many to many table. Previously, my controller looked like this:

```
const Card = require('../models').card;
const Tag = require('../models').tag;
const CardTag = require('../models').card_tag;

module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {
    Promise.all([
      Card.create({title: req.body.card.title, link: req.body.card.link}),
      Tag.create({title: req.body.tag.title})
    ])
      .then(([Card, Tag]) => CardTag.create({cardId: Card.id, tagId: Tag.id}))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  }
```

However, I am now building my controller so that it can handle a single Card and an array of tags. However, when I try to create this controller I return certain undefined values (tag.id) when trying to create a row in my join table. How would I properly do this? (please see the code below). Thanks!

```
const Card = require('../models').card;
const Tag = require('../models').tag;
const CardTag = require('../models').card_tag;

module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {
    Promise.all([
      Card.create({title: req.body.card.title, link: req.body.card.link}),
      req.body.tags.map(tag =>
        Tag.create({title: tag.title})
      )
    ])
      .then(([Card, Tags]) =>
        // How do I properly create a row in the CardTag table? I am having 
        // difficulty getting back tag.id and am right now just returning 
        // an undefined value.
        Tags.map(tag =>
          CardTag.create({cardId: Card.id, tagId: tag.id})
        )
      )
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue in you code is for loop within the `Promise.all` as it is returning nothing , that is why you not getting the result in `.then()`

You can use `bulkCreate` instead of just `create` for `Tag` :

```
module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {
    Promise.all([
        Card.create({title: req.body.card.title, link: req.body.card.link}),
        Tag.bulkCreate(req.body.tags); // <------- Make Change Here --------
    ])
    .then(([Card, Tags]) =>
        Tags.map(tag =>
            CardTag.create({cardId: Card.id, tagId: tag.id})
        )
    )
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  }
};
```